# Custom Select List Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to rid my code of the dependency on `System.Web.Mvc`, since I have extracted my model out to a separate .dll (outside of the MVC project) so that it can be shared among many projects.

I am attempting to create a "custom `SelectListItem`" which is simply just a `class` with two properties of `string Text` and `string Value` and looks like:

```
public class DropDownListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, I am trying to find a way to pass this object into a `DropDownListFor` in my view. Is there anyway to manipulate this so that I can do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value, Model.Values, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Where `Models.Values` is of type `List<DropDownListItem>`.

Comment: You can make your own DropDownList html helper. But the built in one needs that data type.

Comment: you could do `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value, new SelectList(Model.Values, "Value", "Text"), new { @class="form-control" })`

Comment: `SelectList` is a view component. Your model should not contain properties of type `SelectList`, only your view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - not sure I follow - this would be in the view, not the model or view model.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you are saying you want to _"rid my code of the dependency on System.Web.Mvc"_ - what properties in your model have a dependency in `System.Web.MVC`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `SelectListItem` has a dependency on `System.Web.Mvc` so I created my own class to imitate `SelectListItem` and I wanted to pass that into a `DropDownListFor` in my view. Carl's answer seems to accomplish this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo don't need to create a DropDownListItem class - instead you can create your own POCO (Plain-Old-C#-Object) to contain List Options:

For example, let say you have the following class :

```
class MyClass
{
 public int Id {get; set; }
 public string name {get; set; }
}
```

to have dropDownlist which contains a list of MyClass, you can simply use :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Entity.Id, new SelectList(MyClass, "Id", "Name"))
```

The id represent the value of the selection, and the name will be the text displayed within the DropDownList.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You can put the list item in viewbag and get the value in your view like these:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Ligas")
```

and your codebehind

```
Modelo.AdminSitio = Modelo.GetAdminSitio();
ViewBag.Ligas = new SelectList(Modelo.AdminSitio.ListadoLigas, "Value", "Text");
```

when listdoLigas is equals

```
ListadoLigas= (from x in db.Ligas select new DropDownListItem { Value = x.Oid_Liga, Text = x.NombreDeLiga}).ToList();
```

Comment: The `ViewBag` is a bad way of doing this, it should be passed in with the model. Either way, this does not seem to accomplish the task.